# Assigning an array of pointers to a private variable in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In my header file, I have the following code

```
class ExEvent : public Event {
    public:
        ExEvent(
                Item* dst[SIZE],
                );
        ~ExEvent();
        Item* dst[SIZE];
};
```

In the cpp file, I have the following code

```
ExEvent::ExEvent(
        Item * dst[SIZE],
    ) : Event() {
    this->dst = &dst;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: array type 'Item *[15]' is not assignable
    this->dst = &dst;
```

Can someone explain why this error happens and why I cannot assign dst array pointer to this->dst.

Comment: You cannot directly assign arrays. Use `std::copy` instead, or even better use `std::array` in 1st place.

Comment: You have to copy the pointers to the array. You can't assign multiple pointers to a pointer array with '='. Use std::copy or memcpy.

Comment: You can eliminate the `this->` syntax by giving your parameters different names than your member variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In function arguments `type[any-size]` is actually `type*`. I.e. `ExEvent(Item*[SIZE])` is, in fact, `ExEvent(Item**)`.

Hence, to fix the code:

```
ExEvent::ExEvent(Item* src[SIZE])
{
    std::copy_n(src, SIZE, this->dst);
}
```

Make sure that `src` has enough elements.

See [declaring functions: parameter list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Parameter_list) for more details:

> If the type is "array of T" or "array of unknown bound of T", it is replaced by the type "pointer to T"